# Is there a better way to get the checkbox values and make a string from them

Tags: jquery

I have some code like this:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (index) {

            indexArray.push($(this).attr("data-invoiceid"));
        });

            var postData = { values: indexArray.join(',') };
```

As you can see I'm trying to get all the invoiceids for checkboxes checked add them to the values attribute of post data as a comma delimited string. Values could get set to "1,2,5".

So this works finds. I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this where the step of adding the values to the array first could be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use map. Although it still uses an array, it is cleaner and follows a function approach.

```
var indexArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  return $(this).attr("data-invoiceid");
}).get().join(',');
var postData = { values: indexArray};
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   indexArray = "";
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
          indexArray += $(this).data("invoiceid") + ",";
    });
```